# Yeoman Angular Generator -> Grunt versioning of files referenced by JSON

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have an angular app built with Yeoman that grabs GIFs stored in JSON.  Something like this:

```
data.images = [{
            thumbnail: 'http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/482575749_960.jpg',
            gif: 'images/trash.gif'
        },{
            thumbnail: 'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/482575995_960.jpg',
            gif: 'images/jungle.gif''
        },{
            thumbnail: 'http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/482575579_960.jpg',
            gif: 'images/solar.gif'
        }]; '
```

When I `grunt build` grunt-filerev changes the name of the gif.  Then when angular tries to get it, it fails, because the JSON is not correctly pointing at the right file name.  I'm curious if anyone has a solution to automatically update the JSON file to match the revisioning done by grunt-filerev.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you figure out how to achieve this?